# Cannot get if-statement to work within function

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm a complete JS noob who set off on a mission to create a quiz as a first/second-ish project. I suppose there are better ways to do this than the way I'm doing it, but currently I, after a correct submission of the user, want to remove the current iteration from the array which is converted into text through innerHTML, and do the same for the correct answer/explanation. This works well, up until the last bit. After the user completes the last question, it again removes the data from the array, showing "UNDEFINED" in the screen. I figured that, by adding an if statement to see if array.length > 1, I could circumvent this. I tried avoiding this by having a different if statement return true or false and then using && on the function; to no avail. Any and all if statements here give me the errors:

Uncaught ReferenceError: nextQuestion is not defined
    at submitAnswer (VM588 script.js:61)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (quizpage.html:19)

I've attached the html and JS underneath.

```js
var questionsOverview = ["1 - 1+1 = ?", "2 - What food do dieters tend to avoid?", "3 - Best    fast food chain?"];
var answersOverview = ["[A] 1 [B] 3 [C] 2", "[A] Protein [B] Carbs [C] Glucose", "[A] Burger King [B] KFC [C] McDonalds"];
var answersLetter = ["C", "B", "C"];
var score = 0;
var answerUser = "test"

var currentQuestion = questionsOverview[0];

//set buttons as answersLetter
function setRed() {
  document.getElementById(answerUser).style.background = "red";
}
function pressedA() {
  answerUser = "A";
  setRed();
  document.getElementById("B").style.background = "";
  document.getElementById("C").style.background = "";
};

function pressedB() {
  answerUser = "B";
setRed();
document.getElementById("A").style.background = "";
document.getElementById("C").style.background = "";
};

function pressedC() {
  answerUser = "C";
setRed();
document.getElementById("A").style.background = "";
document.getElementById("B").style.background = "";
};

//preps the first question/answer
function changeQuestion() {
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = questionsOverview[0];
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answersOverview[0];
};

//move to the next question
checkForEnd() && function nextQuestion() {
questionsOverview.shift();
answersOverview.shift();
answersLetter.shift();
  changeQuestion();
};

// submit user answer
function submitAnswer() {
  var audio = document.getElementById("tleeni");
  audio.play();
if(answerUser === answersLetter[0]) {
  alert("Correct! You're smart!");
  nextQuestion();
   }
  else {
    alert("Too bad!");
  }
};

function checkForEnd() {
  if (answersOverview.length > 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

```html
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>

<body onload="changeQuestion()">
  <div class="top-header" id="header">
  <font color="white">Quiz</font></div>
  <div class="main-content" id="main-content">
    <h2 id="question">1</h2>
    <h3 id="answer">2</h3>
    <h4 id="score>">scorefiller</h4>
    <div id="buttons">
      <button onClick="pressedA()" class="answers" id="A">A</button>
      <button onClick="pressedB()" class="answers" id="B">B</button>
      <button onClick="pressedC()" class="answers" id="C">C</button>
    </div>
    <button onClick="submitAnswer()" id="submit">Submit answer!</button>
  </div>
  <audio id="tleeni" src="submit.mp3"></audio>
</body>
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Pacifico');
</style>
```

Given that I'm really new to programming I'd appreciate any and all feedback. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue might be here

```js
//move to the next question
checkForEnd() && function nextQuestion() {
questionsOverview.shift();
answersOverview.shift();
answersLetter.shift();
  changeQuestion();
};
```

You're not actually calling the function `nextQuestion`; you're only making a boolean check that is equivalent to `checkForEnd() && true` since a function is a truthy value.

The function declaration is also "lost" hence why you're getting that reference error.

```js
true && function burrito() {
    return '';
}
burrito();
// VM1158:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: burrito is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
checkForEnd() && function nextQuestion() {}
```

This doesn't run each time you click the button, nor does it run each time nextQuestion() is called. It does it once, whenever the code is first loaded. Even if it did all it would be doing is creating a named function expression, which is not useable outside the function itself, ie you can't call `nextQuestion()`.

What you want is to use `checkForEnd()` inside the function and return based on that

```
function nextQuestion() {
  if(!checkForEnd()) return;
  questionsOverview.shift();
  answersOverview.shift();
  answersLetter.shift();
  changeQuestion();
};
```

Comment: `nextQuestion` is never defined either (even if `checkForEnd()` evaluates to `true`), @customcommander is right here

Comment: @shkaper correct forgot that was a named function expression which doesn't define a function into the scope. Though the solution I provided would still fix OP's problem.